# user site-package directory

Tags: python, pip, pdb

I want to know how `'~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` get into my '`sys.path'`.

Is it defined by [PEP 370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) or modified by `pip`(I install package with --user option)?

I also found out that this entry disappears if I move `'~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'`
to `'~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.bak'`.

I add this function [`Ad-hoc data breakpoints`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201311/adhoc_data_breakpoints.html) to `.pystartup`, but nothing changes.

Any one have any idea about this?

Comment: Your `site-package` folder is automatically added to your Python Path, because it is a standard library for external packages/modules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes via the `site` module, which is imported by default by the interpreter unless you give it the `-S` option. (Do that, and you'll see it's no longer added, along with other things.)

Specifically, it's derived from the `site` module's notion of a "user base" directory, which defaults to `~/.local` on POSIX systems. That, in turn, is handled by the `sysconfig` module, as the `userbase` config variable.

See the documentation for the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html) and [`sysconfig`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sysconfig.html) modules for more details.

The reason your data breakpoints don't work is probably just because `site` is imported before your `.pystartup` runs.

Comment: **site.ENABLE_USER_SITE** defaults to True, so If no -S option is specified, **~/.local** will be appended into **sys.path**?

Comment: Yes; isn't that what I said? :)